# UILocalNotification how to show app icon when screen is locked

Tags: ios, icons, uilocalnotification

I'm creating local notification like this:

```
UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = @"Alert body";
notification.alertAction = @"Yes";
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

If it raises when phone is locked only text messages shown before 'slide to unlock' slider. I know it's possible to show some icon with alert. My app has icon with size 57 x 57.
Any suggestions how to do that?

[image: Foursquare can do that]

Comment: It isn't the default that the app icon displays for the local notification?

Comment: I thought so, but on Simulator there are no icon shows. It's not easy to verify behavior on real device at moment

Comment: The icon doesn't show for the notification, or for the app in general in the simulator?

Comment: how did you make it fire when the simulator is locked? 1. i don't know that you can lock a simulator, and 2. i think `presentLocalNotificationNow` should fire right away?

Comment: do you have the full icon set for your application?

Comment: It fires on location change event. Simulator locks via Command + L hot key, presentLocalNotificationNow fires notification well, but app icon does not shows with it.

Comment: @holex, I have 2 icons: Icon.png 57x57 and Icon@2x.png 114x114 px. Is there any other necessary icons?

Comment: @HighFlyer please, find the list of the full icon set in my answer.

Comment: OK, i tested it and i think that's just how the simulator behaves. I tried my app on the simulator and it's text only, and then i tried it on my phone and the icon was there. so no problem.

Answer (score 1):

please, double check you really have the full icon set for your application.

here is the **list of full icon set** for an universal application:

```
- 1024 by 1024 (Retina iTunes artwork)
- 512 by 512 (iTunes artwork)
- 144 by 144 (Retina iPad)
- 114 by 114 (Retina iPhone)
- 96 by 96 (Retina iPad Spotlight)
- 72 by 72 (iPad icon)
- 58 by 58 (Retina iPhone Spotlight)
- 57 by 57 (iPhone icon)
- 48 by 48 (iPad Spotlight)
- 29 by 29 (iPhone Spotlight)
```

Comment: Thank you, we will add absent icons for our app. As @iBlue mentioned simulator does not shows app icon, only device.